# Splitting a large file in python by calling a command line function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to split a file into a number of parts via a python script:

Here is my snippet:

```
def bashCommandFunc(commandToRun):
    process     = subprocess.Popen(commandToRun.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)    
    output      = process.communicate()  
    return output


filepath = "/Users/user/Desktop/TempDel/part-00000"
numParts = "5"

splitCommand = "split -l$((`wc -l < " + filepath + "/" + numParts + ")) " + filepath 


splitCommand:
'split -l$((`wc -l < /Users/user/Desktop/TempDel/part-00000`/5)) /Users/user/Desktop/TempDel/part-00000'
```

If I run this command on a terminal, it splits the file as it's supposed to, but it fails for the above defined subprocess function.

I have tested the function for other generic commands and it works fine.

I believe the character " ` " (tilde) might be an issue,

What is the work around to getting this command to work?
Are there some better ways to split a file from python into "n" parts.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the command you are trying to run as you would in bash?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the edit, here is something that does the job in bash: split -l$((`wc -l < /Users/user/Desktop/TempDel/part-00000`/5))  /Users/user/Desktop/TempDel/part-00000

Comment: I did not see any bash command in your comment, I would not use `shell=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to let Python run this line via a full shell, rather than trying to run it as a command. You can do that by adding `shell=True` option and not splitting your command. But you really shouldn't do that if any part of the command may be influenced by users (huge security risk).

You could do this in a safer way by first calling `wc`, getting the result and then calling `split`. Or even implement the whole thing in pure Python instead of calling out to other commands.

What happens now is that you're calling `split` with first parameter ``` -l$((``wc ```, second parameter `-l`, etc.